# css transforms not working

Tags: css, css-transforms

I feel that this is syntactically correct, and prefixed appropriately. I am trying to make these square brackets go from an opacity of 0 and and transformed position, to an opacity of 1 and translate back to their original position on a hover. for now the opacity does change, but not at the specified tansition timing. the transforms however do not work at all.

my js fiddle is included.

```
.nav-tags {
  display: inline-block;
}

.nav-tags::before
.nav-tags::after{
  display: inline-block;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 3s, opacity 2s;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 3s, opacity 2s;
  transition: transform 3s, opacity 2s;
} 

.nav-tags::before{
  margin-right: 10px;
  content: '[';
    opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(40px);
  -moz-transform: translateX(40px);
  transform: translateX(40px);
} 

.nav-tags::after{
  margin-left: 5px;
  content: ']';
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-40px);
  -moz-transform: translateX(-40px);
  transform: translateX(-40px);
} 

.nav-tags:hover::before,
.nav-tags:hover::after,
.nav-tags:focus::before,
.nav-tags:focus::after {
    opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(500px);
  -moz-transform: translateX(500px);
  transform: translateX(500px);
}
`
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6dpncer1/

Comment: You are missing a comma in between the selectors (`.nav-tags::before
.nav-tags::after{`) and so the `transition` property doesn't even get applied to the two pseudo-elements.

Comment: wow, thanks. i thought i was going crazy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a syntax error that causes the remainder of the code to be ignored.

```
.nav-tags::before // missing a comma here
.nav-tags::after{
  display: inline-block;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 3s, opacity 2s;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 3s, opacity 2s;
  transition: transform 3s, opacity 2s;
}
```

Fixing this gets everything working properly again: https://jsfiddle.net/6dpncer1/1/